# C# Winforms accessing print dialog which opened with another program

Tags: c#, winforms, printdialog

Can I access to print dialog and close it programmatically from Winforms?
This print dialog would be opened by another program like a web browser, notepad or paint.

For example person is on internet explorer and hits ctrl+p on any website then print dialog opens. My console/winform application will find it and hits ok or cancel automatically.

Comment: Why exactly would you want to write software to do this?  This seeems to be a very localized problem.

Comment: @Teomanshipahi:  I'm sure there are other reasons for downvotes, like the near virus-like behavior you're describing.

Comment: So stack-overflow should make people to explain what is the reason for down-vote. so lots of windows api related questions can be considered as a virus-related.  does not make any sense at all.

Comment: Remember @Teomanshipahi. Here you have to be very humble. Sorry to say but most of the members are very egoistic. You can ask it as "interacting with all print request on windows". Do not protest or criticize because people are authorized to do this, it would go only bad for you. Just try to improve the question and specially title.

Comment: Sometimes questions have such a unique requirement that most of the people never need a thing like that or they do it in other (better) way, that is why such question labelled as localized and down-voted. I think forums are for such problems because general ones can be searched out simply. In fact i had needed a same thing, still found no solution but did not think to ask it here. Because i thought that it would be down-voted rather than answered. My apologies to the ones who would feel my words bad because I suspect some would not be able to see any valid justification or even its try.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to perform a simple action, a program such as AutoHotkey might be ideal for this situation. It is designed to help with small tasks such as this. It can perform different actions based on what windows are visible. It can perform keystrokes, which in this case could be Enter, Escape, or Alt-K. If you were wanting more integration with your application, this may not be the proper solution. But if you are just trying to increase automation I think it (or a similar solution) is perfect.

http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: I want to make it programmatically, thanks for the info anyway.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible. However you will have to use unmanaged code, I recommend to use WinDows API to do that. You can find window handle using `FindWindow` function and then you can post corresponding message to that window. Or you can get coordinates of that button and press it after making this window active.

Comment: What in the world is `WinDows API` exactly?  Why is it written that way?  Everything you mention can be done isn't even what he wants to do.  He wants to close a `Window` of another process.  I am pretty sure Windows is going to have a problem with this.

Comment: @Ramhound first, you can kill process using .net managed code, see system.diagnostics namespace. And problems could be here as well as when using windows API - it depends on your system settings not technology. Second, each process may have several windows. So I'm not sure what do you mean by your comment as well as downvote.

Comment: @seeker:  Code or this answer has little value.

Comment: @AustinSalonen as you can see there is no code in any answer to this question. The reason is that it's not so easy and not so quick. But in order to give the direction ( what to use ) I have posted my answer.